# PHP $_GET encoded param return invalid chars

Tags: urlencode

I got a really strange issue that I can't solve, can anyone please suggest a solution? thank you in advance :)

I want to pass a complete url to a script, the script will check the url and do a meta refresh to redirect to it, so assume my script is **goto.php** and I want it redirect to:

`http://www.google.com/?name=david&param=gender`

So I enter this in my browser:

```
www.mydomain.com/goto.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F%3Fname%3Ddavid%26param%3Dgender
```

But my goto.php script get:

```
http://www.google.com/?name=david¶m=gender
```

As you can see, the "&" is missed, here is the code of my goto.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>checking</title>
<meta name="robots" content="noindex,nofollow" />
</head>
<body>
<?php echo $_GET ['u'];?>
</body>
</html>
```

although if I add

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=<?php echo $_GET ['u'];?>" />
```

it works in some browser, but in some other browser, it won't work, because the $_GET['u'] didn't return a valid url.

Thank you once more for any suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you have an issue with charset encoding/decoding.  Whats the output of your "php -i"?

**edit**

I just gave it another try and your script is fine.  The issue is that your URL is not escaped for HTML.  If you look at the source of your page, then you will realize that everything looks fine.

You must escape all ampersands (&) before you output to HTML.  Use htmlspecialchars() or htmlentities() for that.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php

```
<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_GET['u']); ?>
```

Comment: &para; shows in HTML as ¶...  so it must be escaped = )

Answer (score 0):

Please change the line

```
<?php echo $_GET['u']; ?>
```

to the following line

```
<?php echo urldecode($_GET['u']); ?>
```

Comment: thank you for your reply, but as you can see at http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php, the $_GET param is already url decoded ( "The GET variables are passed through urldecode()." ), if I decode it one more time, I get the same result.